# Exporting a column with Tab & New line from Informix Database to Excel

Tags: sql, database, newline, informix

Need help in Exporting a Comments column with Tab & New line from Informix Database to Excel - We have a big query that fetches around 25 K data from Informix Database and request is to have them dumped to excel file for consumption.

The query is complete and one of the comments column has tab & New line entered that is causing records in excel to span across multiple rows causing more clean up effort as around 2 K rows have tabs/new lines.

Have googled a lot and there is not a solution that can be used directly in a query - Can you help if anyone faced similar issue and if there is a solution

Comment: What program(s) are you using to export the data?  What format do you (does Microsoft Excel) expect for CSV data containing tabs and newlines?  My [SQLCMD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iiug-software-repository/files/ESQL/) program (wholly unrelated to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the same name) has an option for generating a variant of CSV output.  It uses a backslash at the end of a line to continue it to the next — which may or may not be what Excel expects.  If Excel is happier without the backslash, it would not be hard to omit it.

Comment: Concat `"` at the start and end of the column with the new line

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like REPLACE() to remove the newline/tab before doing the unload?

```
> create table t1(c1 varchar(200));
Table created.

> insert into t1 values ('test1'||chr(10)||'  test');
1 row(s) inserted.

> insert into t1 values ('test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'  test');
1 row(s) inserted.

> select * from t1;
c1  test1
      test

c1  test2
      test

2 row(s) retrieved.

> select replace(c1,chr(10),' ') from t1;
(expression)  test1   test
   testsion)  test2

2 row(s) retrieved.

> select replace(replace(c1,chr(10),' '),chr(13),' ') from t1;
(expression)  test1   test
(expression)  test2    test
2 row(s) retrieved.

> 

> unload to t1.unl select replace(replace(c1,chr(10),' '),chr(13),' ') from t1;
2 row(s) unloaded.

> !cat t1.unl
test1   test|
test2    test|
>
```